# Elseif Statement doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I can not understand why the Elseif-Statement doesn't work. I've tested the first If-Statement and it works like intended, but the Elseif-Statement doesn't, although the syntax is kinda the same as before. 
Can someone spot my error?

/edit: this is the full code. Sorry, I thought it would be easier if I just post my problem, because the code before works like a charm and I didn't thought it would cause any error. Still learning this.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim Row As Long
Dim Clm As Long
lastrow1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row


        Table1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X2:X" & lastRow)
        Source1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E3:J" & lastrow1)
        Row = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").row
        Clm = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Column


For Each cl In Table1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Source1, 5, False)
Row = Row + 1
Next cl

Set range1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow)
Set range2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
Set range3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F" & lastRow)


For Each cl In range1

If range3.Value <> "" And range2.Value <> "" Then
range1.Value = range3.Value


    ElseIf range3.Value = "" And range2.Value <> "" Then
    range1.Value = range2.Value

        Else: range3.Value = "" And range2.Value = ""
        range1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Source1, 6, False)

    End If
    Next cl
```

Comment: That code cannot even possibly run because you cannot have a variable name starting with a number.

Comment: You are not looping properly.  you are doing a loop but still referring to the entire range each time.  You should be getting many errors.  You cannot use numbers as variables.  You cannot equate a full range to a single value.  and there is more.  It shouldn't even compile.

Comment: I replaced the original text with numbers for this example.

Comment: do not do that, please show the code as you have it.  It makes us focus on the wrong error.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry, is this edit allright?

Comment: @Sven - let me guess - you also have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code?

Comment: You still should be getting an error on the first if.  You should be get a "type mismatch" error there.  If you are not then you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in the code.  Remove that and fix the errors instead of ignoring them.

Comment: If you're asking for help debugging your code, post your code, and not something you made up on the fly. Inventing code for your post can introduce new problems (as you've done here) or change it enough to hide the actual problem. Also, it helps if you learn to properly indent your code, as it makes the flow of execution more clear. It can also often make the problem very clear.

Comment: Ya, I edited it. You're right with the code. I thought it would be easier for you guys, if I only post the code which causes problems, because the code above worked fine.. It wasn't intended..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the comments above.

There is a time and place to use `On Error Resume Next` but is should be followed up with `On Error Goto 0` as soon as possible.  Otherwise simple errors are covered and you get no help as to why the code is not working.

As to this code.  You cannot equate multi range references to a single value it will give you a `Type Mismatch` error.

So it you are going to loop through a range, arrays would be preferable, use that to find one cell at a time.

Also the Else was slightly wrong, you do not need a Boolean statement in the Else, it is the catch all.

use this:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Source1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E3:J" & lastrow1)

Set A = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow)
Set B = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
Set C = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F" & lastRow)


For i = 2 To lastRow
    If C(i).Value <> "" And B(i).Value <> "" Then
        A(i).Value = C(i).Value
    ElseIf C(i).Value = "" And B(i).Value <> "" Then
        A(i).Value = B(i).Value
    Else
        A(i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(A(i).Value, Source1, 6, False)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: according to his original code the last Else should be ElseIf C(i).Value = "" And B(i).Value = "" Then

Comment: @HardCore no, that is what is left.  There is no need for it.

Comment: there should be the option C(i).Value <> "" And B(i).Value = "" that you left out

Comment: @HardCore I think you are reading too much into it.  There are only three outcomes.  Either we insert the value from C, the Value from B or the result of the VLOOKUP.  All others are ignored.  at least that is the way I read the code.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, there are only these three outcomes.

Comment: I've tested the code and had to change `For i = 2 To lastRow` to `For i = 1 To lastRow`otherwise Q2 would be empty. But even if condition 1 is fulfilled it gives me an error at the Else-Statement (runtime error 1004 - " 
Unable to get the VLookup property of the Worksheetfuntion class")

Comment: @sven then your value in Range A is not found in the lookup range.  that is data not code.

Comment: @HardCore, the last else instruction in the original post is `not an elseif` ... it is an `else` followed by a second instruction `range3.Value = "" And range2.Value = ""` which is actually a badly formed instruction ... it is two instructions on one line, separated by `:`  .... this is a very good example why you should never put more than one instruction per line, it only leads to confusion